# Multiple XAMPP local sites defined by ports auto configuration

Tags: apache, web, xampp, webserver

I currently have XAMPP running multiple sites, and the configuration, albeit simple, just becomes messy the more I add.

Currently I have an index.php which lists all directories in my /www/ folder, and offers a link to each site to access locally/internally. However in order to set these up I need to:

CREATE FOLDER:

```
/.../www/site4
```

Edit HOSTS:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost-site1
127.0.0.1   localhost-site2
127.0.0.1   localhost-site3
127.0.0.1   localhost-site4
```

Edit HTTPD.CONF

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/.../www/localhost-site4"
    ServerName localhost-site4
    ServerAlias localhost-site4
    ServerAdmin root@example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

PHP Site Index:

```
<ul>
<?php 
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
foreach ($dirs as $key => $value) {
    echo "<li><a href='http://localhost-".$value."/'>".$value."</a></li><br/>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

---

Instead of having a huge list of sites everywhere, I wanted to automate this a bit better ***and be able to access the sites from different devices on my LAN*** so I thought I could use different ports instead.

HOSTS much simpler:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

However, the HTTPD conf gets more complex as you have to listen for each port

```
Listen 80
Listen 8001
Listen 8002
Listen 8003
<VirtualHost *:8001>
    DocumentRoot "C:/.../www/localhost-site1"
    ServerName localhost:8001
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8002>
    DocumentRoot "C:/.../www/localhost-site2"
    ServerName localhost:8002
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8003>
    DocumentRoot "C:/.../www/localhost-site3"
    ServerName localhost:8003
</VirtualHost>
```

etc

Is there a way to make this dynamic somehow via php using just the folder structure (eg `/www/site1-8001/` to somehow auto `Listen on 8001`, create a link to `http://site1:8001/` and also add this `VirtualHost` line

Comment: Using ports instead of names won't make things easier. Instead you should change the current strategy to define an explicit separate virtual host for each of those sites. Use the fallback virtual host inside the apache http server instead, that is the first first host that is defined in the configuration. Then you can use a single implementation of rewriting rules that take the `HTTP_HOST` as specified in the incoming requests and internally rewrites the requests to a corresponding folder in your local file system, if that exists.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do you mean, keep only one `localhost` VirtualHost setup, however use `IF` or `IfModule` to check the request header and then redirect? Like: `<If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} == 'localhost/site2'">
    Redirect permanent "/" "localhost/mylocalsite2/"
</If>`

Comment: I posted an answer describing the rewriting setup in its most simple form.

Answer (score 0):

You chould change the current strategy to define an explicit separate virtual host for each of those sites. Use the fallback virtual host inside the apache http server instead, that is the first first host that is defined in the configuration. Then you can use a single implementation of rewriting rules that take the HTTP_HOST as specified in the incoming requests and internally rewrites the requests to a corresponding folder in your local file system, if that exists.

Inside that single http host, that responds to *all* incoming requests, you can then use a simple rewriting along this approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

You need to have the rewriting module installed and activated inside the apache http server (absolute standard). Such a rule should be implemented inside the http server's host configuration, as it is part of the global setup in my eyes. You could also use a *distributed* configuration file for the (typically called ".htaccess"), but that comes with a number of disadvantages. You will find endless examples for such setup here on SO, though.

Above rule would rewrite *any* incoming request to a folder inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that single virtual host. That would suggest a file system layout along this suggestion:

```
/var/www/hosts/local-site-1/...
              /local-site-2/...
              /local-site-3/...
              /local-site-4/...
```

You'd still have to setup local name resolution for each site, but that is a single line in the "hosts" file for each site.